# How to add 2 columns of checkboxes to Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I want to add several (about 8) checkboxes in 2 columns below the string and the textbox and above the buttons "Aceptar" and "Cancelar"

[image]

I have tried to do a Jpanel inside another Jpanel, but i does not work since the subpanel does not align where i want to (or i dont know how to align it)

```
    JLabel texto_titulo_qliksense = new JLabel();
    texto_titulo_qliksense.setText("Nombre del cuadro de mando :");    
    texto_titulo_qliksense.setBounds(20, 50, 700, 25);

    JCheckBox checkBox1 = new JCheckBox("Stream 1");  
    checkBox1.setBounds(75,100, 50,50);  
    JCheckBox checkBox2 = new JCheckBox("Stream 2");  
    checkBox2.setBounds(10,150, 50,50);  

    textField = new JTextField(80);       
    textField.setBounds(200,53,220,20);

    JLabel texto3 = new JLabel(); 
    texto3.setText("Usuario: " + usuario);  

    JButton aceptar = new JButton();
    aceptar.setText("Aceptar");
    aceptar.setActionCommand(comandoAceptar);
    aceptar.setBounds(90, 250, 100, 30); 
    aceptar.addActionListener(this);

    JButton cancelar = new JButton();
    cancelar.setText("Cancelar"); 
    cancelar.setActionCommand(comandoCancelar);
    cancelar.setBounds(250, 250, 100, 30); 
    cancelar.addActionListener(this);

    panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setBorder(null);
    subpanel = new JPanel();
    subpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Subpanel 1"));
    subpanel.setBounds(250, 450, 250, 250);
    subpanel.setAlignmentX(java.awt.Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    subpanel.setAlignmentX(java.awt.Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    subpanel.setVisible(true);
    panel.setBounds(250, 100, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: use `GridLayout` (or `GridBagLayout`)  as `Layout` for the panel: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: It is necessary to use a layout? its a very small program, wont be easier just to use absolute positioning?

Comment: 1) *"wont be easier just to use absolute positioning?"* Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) Tip: Add @CarlosHeuberger (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: IMO its much easier to use layout managers - being *used* to it (since beginning, only *needed* abs. pos. after years) - no needed to calculate sizes, find correct positioning, **much** easier to maintain, .... (and by posted screenshot we see the result)

Answer (score 1):

> its a very small program, wont be easier just to use absolute positioning?

Easier than *this*?

[image]

```
JPanel ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40,4,40,4));

JPanel pageStartPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
ui.add(pageStartPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
pageStartPanel.add(new JLabel("Nombre del cuadro de mando:"));
pageStartPanel.add(new JTextField(12));

JPanel checkPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
ui.add(checkPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
for (int ii=1; ii<9; ii++) {
    checkPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox " + ii));
}
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null, 
        ui, 
        "Exportar CdM de Qliksense", 
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```